# How to take value from a label from WPF Itemscontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

good afternoon, I am writing this question to see if you can help me with a problem that I am having, it is probably easy to solve but I have not been able to make it work for days.

WPF programming I created an itemscontrols where I list a list with all the books I have, until there everything works perfect, my problem is that I want to do that when I press a button I take the value of the name of the book to use it in another part.

Then I leave the fragment of code that I have so that I can understand a little more

```
<StackPanel Name="stkMain">
    <ItemsControl Name="itmCntrl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Name="stk">
                        <materialDesign:Card Width="300" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Name="img" Source="{Binding PhotoPath}" Height="300" Width="240" Stretch="Fill" Cursor="Hand" />
                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Content="MORE"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8" Click="Button_Click"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="nan" Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </materialDesign:Card>
                    </materialDesign:TransitioningContent>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see for each item created I have an image, a label and a button, and basically what I can not do is that by pressing the button I take the value of the label

I hope I can lend a hand with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a `Button_Click` method `sender` parameter is a Button which has `DataContext` ptoperty. `DataContext` is a single object with `Name` property:

```
// c#
Button b = (Button)sender;
object dc = b.DataContext;
//// cast dc to correct type, e.g.
// Book book = (Book)dc;
// string name = book.Name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I worked perfectly, it was the one you told me about.